# How to return a exception message to the user in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling, firebase-authentication

is it possible to return an exception message back to the user? If Yes, how may i achieve it? I want to let the user know the exception message returned whenever occured. Plus, i don't want my app to crash at the time when the exception occurs.

To be more specific, i want to return the error message back to the user while the user is trying to login. I have used Firebase as my auth provider.

I have inlcuded my code below for a better understanding.

Thank you in advance.

```
 Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);

      throw Exception('Some Error occured. ');
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e, _) {
      print(e);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show an error message using ScaffoldMessenger to the user

```dart
   Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    BuildContext context,
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
      
      throw Exception('Some Error occured. ');
      
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e, _) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(e.toString()),
    ));
    } catch (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(e.toString()),
    ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is thrown back to the user, but still at the time of the exception the app crashes. How can i avoid the app crashing at the time of the exception please?

Comment: Application 'throw Exception('Some Error occurred.');' Is it crashing because of this line?

Comment: `Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(wrong-password, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., {code: wrong-password, message: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., nativeErrorMessage: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., nativeErrorCode: 17009, additionalData: {}}, null))` 

The program pauses and crashes at this time while i debug my application.

Comment: If you are getting the error inside the try{} block, the application should not pause

Comment: The program doesn't crash when i run my application without debugging. Is there any way to return the error message in a more attractive way? Like a toast message maybe? Only if you'd know. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast to show a toast message. Also, you can parse the error objects and show only the 'message' value. 

Comment: check how it's handled here: https://github.com/PeterHdd/Firebase-Flutter-tutorials/blob/master/firebase_google_sign_in_tutorial/lib/screens/sign_in_page.dart#L144 @ShehanLiyanaarachchi

Comment: I will try this out, thank you very much again! Cheers!